# How to Share the environment Paths between Bash, fish and zsh shells

Tags: bash, fish, zsh

fish Shell doesn't recognize the **node** command as well as **zsh** too.

But the **bash** does, So How Can I Share **Environment Path** between all of the Shells

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These shells do not use the same configuration files. Normally the `PATH` environment variable is set in `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` which are files read by `bash` (and `dash`) but by neither of `fish` or `zsh`.

But you can manually execute your profile files (this sets PATH and does other things as well)

For **fish** you can use the script provided here: https://superuser.com/a/447777

For **zsh** create a `~/.zprofile`file with the following contents (and put anything else in `~/.profile`):

```
emulate sh -c '. ~/.profile'
```

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/446925/re-use-profile-for-fish
and https://superuser.com/questions/187639/zsh-not-hitting-profile